# Xamarin Android - SeekBar within Preference events not called

Tags: android, events, xamarin, progress, seekbar

I'm trying to make a custom `Preference` within a `PreferenceActivity` that uses a `SeekBar`. The problem that I'm having is that I can't seem to get the events to be called.

Preference within options.xml:

```
<Preference
    android:key="radius"
    android:title="Radius"
    android:layout="@layout/slider_preference" />
```

slider_preference.xml:

```
<SeekBar
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:progress="4000"
  android:max="9000"
  android:id="@+id/seeker"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_weight="2" />
```

OptionsActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "Options", ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class OptionsActivity : PreferenceActivity
{
    //...

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var radius = (Preference)FindPreference(Preferences.RADIUS);

        View radiusView = radius.GetView(null, null);
        SeekBar seek = radiusView.FindViewById<SeekBar>(Resource.Id.seeker);
        TextView bottomTitle = radiusView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.bottom_text);

        seek.ProgressChanged += delegate
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                bottomTitle.Text = (seek.Progress + 1000).ToString() + " feet";
            });
        };

        seek.Progress = 9000;
    }
    //...
}
```

Using breakpoints, I was able to determine that the `ProgressChanged` event is only called when the seek.Progress is set programmatically. Whenever I change it in the UI, the event is not called. It seems to me that there are two different `View`s containing the `SeekBar` and the one that I'm actually touching is not the same as the one in the code.

How can I solve this issue?